# Deploying Spring Boot war in a Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Boot app (war) in the standalone Tomcat server and every time I get an error about logger. Do you have any ideas about this case?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerProvider.java:29)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:33)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.<clinit>(LoggerProviders.java:28)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2263)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:66)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:381)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 28 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 46 more
```

As you can see, I'm using tomcat 8.0.24, Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE, and java.version 1.7.
My project is very simple (it is working as a jar):

**1. Main app**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**2. Controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

  @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "/home"})
  String index() {
      return "index";
  }
}
//index.html is in the tamplates folder.
```

**3. Pom.xml**

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>HelloWorld</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <!--<start-class>demo.Application</start-class>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

... etc
```

`application.properties` are clean.

Comment: Do you have anything in Tomcat's lib directory?

Comment: Yes, I do. There are libs: annotations-api, catalina-ant, catalina-ha, catalina-storeconfig, catalina-tribes, catalina, ecj-4.4.2, el-api, jasper-el,
jasper, jsp-api, servlet-api, tomcat-api, tomcat-coyote, tomcat-dbcp, tomcat-i18n, tomcat-jdbc, tomcat-jni, tomcat-util-scan, tomcat-util, tomcat-websocket, websocket-api.

Comment: I tried your exact setup and everything works fine. It must be something you're not showing, or maybe try rebuilding your war, maybe you changed something.

Comment: Surprisingly, last time my Tomcat was working under jre 1.7. I have changed it to 1.8, also changed this project to 1.8 too and now it has no errors. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, I even tried running Tomcat 8 under a JRE 1.7 and also got no errors, so I'm not convinced it was that either. Anyway, your issue seems to have disappeared now.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone deleted my prev post, but I still see it as a class loader problem.

... I'm using the spring-hateoas together with the Spring boot from a war in a Tomcat... and get the same error. I trust it might be a classloader problem, but haven't found the right solution yet.

Avoiding the slf4j-api will make the app start up, without the LoggerFactory NoClassDefFoundError, but the hateoas classes are only present at compile time, not runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency on slf4j in your pom.xml.

Probably slf4j-api and the jdk logging implementation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See also [how to log in tomcat using slf4j and java.util.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990564/how-to-looging-in-tomcat-using-slf4j-and-java-util-logging)

Comment: I was trying to add slf4j earlier but it does not fix this. The same error with these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Add sl4j-api jar in the dependancy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```